# How to deny database access to login user sa and windows mode in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have create a username 'Rohi' and password 'Rohi@21' in SQL Server 2008 R2. 
Also set their roles like sysadmin and db_owner. Also have create the database and tables for this user. All this things I have done programatically using vb.net.

Now I am facing the issue that How to prevent the database from SQL server users like sa and Windows mode?

This database should only be accessible to user Rohi and not to anyone else. 
The database should not be accessible to SQL Server Logins (SA) or Windows Authentication Logins.

Is there a way to deny access to the database for other users ?

Comment: sa is a sysadmin role member, you cannot deny a sysadmin access to anything, nor should you need to as if you don't trust a user with those rights you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 3):

- Contact Microsoft
- Have them rewrite SQL Server.

This is the ONLY way to do it. By design, the SA and other server level administrators have access to all databases. If this is not acceptable, the only way to get this changed is to change the design of SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. 
Kindly suggest an alternate strategy for securing my database from unauthorised access

Comment: What you mean? SA is the system administrator. There is no unauthorized access - system admins need access for their work. Alternate Strategy? Go back to the drawing board with a little more realism.